# Rviz2 Moveit Error In The Tutorial

Tags: rviz, moveit, ros-humble, errors, moveit-tutorial

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS and ROS2 Humble. I am trying to build Moveit for some robotic applications but I could not do Build and Run. https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/tutorials/your_first_project/your_first_project.html#id1

When I use this command: `ros2 launch moveit2_tutorials demo.launch.py` Rviz opens empty without a robot and closes suddenly.

I got this error:

```
[rviz2-1] [ERROR] [1710372329.525649268] [rviz2.motion_planning_frame]: Action server: /recognize_objects not available
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1710372329.539875069] [rviz2.motion_planning_frame]: MoveGroup namespace changed: / -> . Reloading params.
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1710372329.697520444] [rviz2.RDFLoader]: Loaded robot model in 0.00419209 seconds
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1710372329.697597252] [rviz2.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'gen3'...
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1710372329.697630362] [rviz2.robot_model]: No root/virtual joint specified in SRDF. Assuming fixed joint
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1710372329.883764718] [rviz2.kdl_kinematics_plugin]: Joint weights for group 'manipulator': 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
[rviz2-1] malloc(): invalid size (unsorted)
[ERROR] [rviz2-1]: process has died [pid 99277, exit code -6, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/rviz2/rviz2 -d /home/ws_moveit/install/moveit2_tutorials/share/moveit2_tutorials/launch/kinova_moveit_config_demo.rviz --ros-args -r __node:=rviz2 --params-file /tmp/launch_params_o26kllwv --params-file /tmp/launch_params_9fx0hknk --params-file /tmp/launch_params_1wqbaw8b --params-file /tmp/launch_params_lj9_1y2l --params-file /tmp/launch_params_q1z3end1'].
```

Does anyone have idea about solution? How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I have answered in your last request the first step.

1- After you have successfully installed and compiled the MoveIt packages from this page  [tutorial](https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/tutorials/getting_started/getting_started.html) you will need to reproduce the step 3.1 from this tutorial: [Build and Run](https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/tutorials/your_first_project/your_first_project.html#id1)

2- just navigate to the ws_moveit workspace if you are not there:

```
cd ws_moveit
```

3- SOURCE this workspace

```
source install/setup.bash
```

4- Launch your launch file

```
ros2 launch moveit2_tutorials demo.launch.py
```

5 - When rviz2 opens, go to Add, scroll down and select the RobotModel plugin

[image]

6 - In the robot model plugin topic add /robot_description topic and the robot will be displayed

[image]